# php excel found unreadable content

Tags: php, excel, yii2, phpexcel

I use php excel in many of my reports and this is the weirdest errors I've ever have.

This is my code:

```
$firstCol = "A";
$endCol = "E";

$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($firstCol."1:".$endCol."1")->setCellValue('A1', 'LAPORAN LABA RUGI')->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(array('font' => array('bold' => 'true', 'size' => '18')));

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($firstCol.$rowNum.":".$endCol.$rowNum)->setCellValue('A'.$rowNum, 'December 2021')->getStyle('A'.$rowNum)->applyFromArray(array('font' => array('size' => '16')));
$rowNum += 2;

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($firstCol.$rowNum.":".$endCol.$rowNum)->setCellValue('A'.$rowNum, "Penjualan")->getStyle('A'.$rowNum)->applyFromArray(array('font' => array('bold' => 'true')));
$rowNum++;

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A".$rowNum, 'Label');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("B".$rowNum, 'Total');
$rowNum++;

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A".$rowNum, 'asdasd');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("B7", 'asdfg');
```

my exported excel file got "excel found unreadable content" error. But when I remove one or more of the setCellValue lines, or change 'asdfg' to 'Total', it works just fine.

What could be the problem? Please help.

Comment: Seems very odd. Have you tried removing all `setCellValue` lines and then adding them one at a time until there is failure?

Comment: yup, tried that. And it got error when I add the "B7 asdfg" line.

Comment: Does changing the cell to B8, or C7 do anything? My thinking is maybe B7 is interfering with the mergeCells previously

Comment: I tried B8, F8, G20 but still got the same error

Comment: Removing everything BUT that one, does it still trigger error?

Comment: I tried to let B7 as it is and remove other setCellValue lines one at a time, and it works. The error will trigger only if all lines are available.